# Alternative relational data storage methods for Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Honestly, I do not enjoy working with SQLite on Android beyond trivial apps. It is a real pain to keep the database structure up to date between app versions and actually writing data access code is not much fun either when one is used to working with Hibernate and Entity Framework.

I am hoping there are alternative ways for me to store persistent data that will be reliable and robust. E.g. would serializing a collection of objects to external storage be an option? I expect my data to be around 5MB at most at any time.

Are there any other options? Specifically, I am downloading e.g. stock lists and contact details from a server, then allow the user to mark records as processed, etc. I was thinking of an XML file, but that creates another problem: how to robustly handle XML in java using the Android API.

Obviously first prize would have been a NoSQL database, but I know that's not going to be practical even if a stable mobile version existed.

Comment: you can check Realm if it suits your requirement

Comment: you can use `realm` instead of SQLite.

Comment: You could try out [Realm](https://realm.io/).

Comment: Guys, do you think I should check out Realm? LOL

Answer (score 2):

Do you look SQLite Android Framework wich give you DAO and generate the database from POJO for you (as Hibernate) ?

For example : http://greenrobot.org/greendao/
Then you can easily update and versioning your database structure.

Comment: There are others as well, search for "Android ORM".